# A relatively new blog seems to be getting very poor Google indexing

Tags: seo

I have [a new blog](http://www.glowingstart.com) that is 2 months old. In the first few weeks, it was getting indexed nicely and my GoogleWebmaster reports were showing that it was getting crawled and began ranking for some terms.

Then as I kept writing, the GoogleWebmaster report thinned out and showed less and less terms that this blog ranks for. Now there are only 4 terms with one of them being my name.

Is there something I need to do to keep the old posts to remain indexed and crawled?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

The website seems pretty slow. Here it needs 20+ seconds to load completely. Google does not like slow websites

Comment: @Marcel yeah I know..that site is really slow. I have no idea why. But good point on fixing that!

Comment: Hi. Sorry I had a much bigger answer, but it seems that something went wrong when this question migrated to webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Anyway, there could also be a duplicate content issue. You show on the index page the complete content of each blogpost. The same content is shown on the single page. Maybe you should check your canonical tags, or even better: show the excerpt on archive pages instead of the complete content. 

When you would show the excerpt, you also solve the speed issue, because the youtube videos will not be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

When I was working on WordPress sites, I always used [this free plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) to track things.

If you built the site yourself, it's definitely possible you've got errors with the way you've laid out the site. Otherwise, it could be a number of other factors. You'll need some kind of analytical tool to track down the problem.

It could be url structure, could be your sitemap is out of date, could be you're overusing terms or tags. Slow site speed is definitely a killer, though. That's what you need to work out. It might be that you've got some errors in your layout files or plugins not playing well together.

There's a lot of possibilities, but fixing the speed issue should get you a long way.

Keep in mind, there have also been a lot of [major algorithm updates](http://moz.com/google-algorithm-change) lately, too, so that could be part of it. If your site's doing anything that make Penguin or Hummingbird unhappy, that could be another part of the problem. Hope that helps a bit.